# Rails Webpacker - How to access objects defined in webpack entry file from views [HTML file]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I have a Rails 6 application and using Webpacker for assets.

I have the following code in file `app/javascript/packs/application.js` :

```
export var Greeter = {
    hello: function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

And I have the following script in one of my view (HTML) file:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   Greeter.hello();
 });
</script>
```

*Note: I am using JQuery and it is working fine.*

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: **Greeter** is not defined.

How can we use `libraryTarget` and `library` to expose the bundled modules, so that it can be accessed from HTML files as well ?

Or, is there any other way of doing it using Rails Webpacker ?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

To do this without directly mutating the `window` object in your application code, you'll want to export `Greeter` as a named export from your `application.js` pack and extend the Webpack config `output` to designate the library name and target `var` (or `window` will also work).

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

environment.config.merge({
  output: {
    library: ['Packs', '[name]'], // exports to "Packs.application" from application pack
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  }
})

// app/javascript/packs/application.js

export {
  Greeter
}
```

```html
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   Packs.application.Greeter.hello();
 });
</script>
```

The `library` name is arbitrary. Using the `[name]` placeholder is optional but allows you to export to separate modules if you're using multiple "packs".

Answer (score 1):

As I cannot comment [rossta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771838/rossta)'s answer, here is what I had to do. My default config was:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

module.exports = environment
```

and I just had to add the additionnal config in it:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js
    
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.config.merge({
  output: {
    library: ['Packs', '[name]'], // exports to "Packs.application" from application pack
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  }
})

module.exports = environment
```

After that, as mentioned by [rossta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771838/rossta), each symbol which is exported in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` can be accessed from the DOM as `Packs.application.<symbol>`.

Answer (score 0):

in app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
import Greeter from '../greeter.js'
Greeter.hello()
```

and in app/javascript/greeter.js:

```
export default {
  hello : function(){
    console.log('hello')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I want to call `Greeter.hello()` from one of the HTML page and not from a JS file.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the issue exposing `Greeter` object to `window` as follows:

```
export var Greeter = {
    hello: function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

window.Greeter = Greeter;
```

However, I am still looking for a Webpack way of accomplishing this.